# Allow timer to start jenkins pipeline only if a global environment variable is set

Tags: windows, jenkins, global-variables, flags, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have set a global environment varaiable in jenkins - `flag` which takes in values `on` and `off`

I have multiple declarative pipelines in jenkins, some of which get triggered based on timers.

Now I don't want the timers to trigger the scheduled pipelines when `flag` is set to `on`.

One way is to use the `when {expression {env.flag == 'off' }}` in all the stages in all the pipelines triggered by timer. I can't even apply it to `stages` at once but instead have to apply it individually to all `stage` inside `stages`. Is there a better way?

How can I accomplish this, preferably without installing any new plugins?

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to throw an error if `flag = on` in the beginning of your pipeline, but that would mean having a failing pipeline as soon the flag is `on`. But you can avoid the `FAILURE` with some `post` function treatment.

Else you can try using scripted pipeline instead of declarative one :

```
node('your node'){
 if(!flag){
  stage(){...}
 }
}
```